# Proving a relation is an equivalence class and finding [5]

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

The question asks to prove that the following relation is an equivalence relation on the set of integers and find the equivalence class of the number 5.

$ (x,y) ∈ R$ if and only if  $x + 2y$  is divisible by 3 .

I was able to prove that the relation is reflexive but I'm not quite sure how to prove that the relation is symmetric and transitive, as well as [5].

Answer (score 0):

To prove symmetry, you need to prove: if $(x,y) \in R$, then $(y,x) \in R$. That is, if $x+2y$ is divisible by $3$, then $y+2x$ is divisible by $3$. **Hint:** What is $(x+2y)+(y+2x)$?

To prove transitivity, you need to prove: if $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$, then $(x,z) \in R$. That is, if $x+2y$ is divisible by $3$ and $y+2z$ is divisible by $3$, then $x+2z$ is divisible by $3$. **Hint:** Add $(x+2y)+(y+2z)$.

To find the equivalence class of $5$, you need to find the set of all numbers $x$ such that $(x,5) \in R$. What does it mean to have $(x,5) \in R$? Can you characterize all such $x$ that satisfy this?

Comment: to find the equivalence class, do you always find the set of all number $x$ such that $(x,n)∈R$?

Comment: The equivalence class of an element is defined to be the set of all elements that are related to it under the equivalence relation. So the equivalence class of $n$ is defined to be $\{x \mid (x,n) \in R\}$. This could equivalently be written as $\{x \mid (n,x) \in R\}$ since $(x,n) \in R \Leftrightarrow (n,x) \in R$.

Comment: I'm kind of lost, then what would be [5] in this case?

Comment: The notation $[n]$ denotes the equivalence class of $n$. So $[5]$ is the equivalence class of $5$, which by the definition I gave in my previous comment, is:
$$[5]=\{x \mid (x,5) \in R\}$$
or equivalently
$$[5]=\{x \mid (5,x) \in R\}.$$

Comment: so is that the answer?

Comment: No, because you need to figure out what *is* the set $\{x \mid (5,x) \in R\}$. Which *numbers* $x$ are in this set? Can you list some? Is there a pattern to them?

Comment: would it be $(3m-5)/2$ where $m∈N$?

Comment: Yes, although there is a "cleaner" way to describe these numbers. Write a few of them out for different values of $m \in \mathbb{N}$, and see what their remainders are modulo $3$.

Answer (score 0):

if $(x,y)$ then $x+2y = 3k$

$x = 3k-2y$

If the relation is symmetric then $(y,x)$ and $y +2(3k+2y) =  9k-3y$ must also be divisible by 3.  And it is!

If the relation is transative.

$(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$

$x = 3j - 2y\\
y = 3k - 2z$

imply $(x,z)$

$x = 3j - 6k + 4z\\
x+2z = 3j - 6k + 6z$

And the RHS is indeed divisible by 3.

This has all been a bit messy.

It might be cleaner to say $(x,y)\implies x \equiv y \pmod 3$

Prove to yourself that these are the same relations.

The equivalence class that includes 5.

$\{\cdots,-1,2,5,8,\cdots \}$